# How to give proper input and output format and filepath in Hadoop Streaming

Tags: matlab, shell, hadoop, octave, hadoop-streaming

I have created a Matlab program, that i have to run it in Hadoop. For testing purpose i am using Octave for Hadoop image processing. I have working Hadoop environment with clusters. For image processing I am using Hadoop streaming jar file. Shell script created for octave simple image processing program. Local file system image files were used in shell script it was successful. But now i am going to run it in Hadoop environment. For that i should give image which is stored in HDFS. I tried this in Hadoop but it wont work and wont give output image. For example

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/octave <<EOF
rgbImage = imread("/usr/2003vre.jpg");
imwrite(rgbImage,"/usr/OT/newnewnew.jpg");
```

Here the file path i have mention is in local file system. Please tell me how should i give input file path of HDFS in this script.

And please tell me, where should i give input for this octave program (within the script or hadoop streaming input stage) like below

```
hadoop@isro:/usr/local/grid/hadoop$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar -mapper /usr/OT/octave.sh -file /usr/OT/octave.sh input /usr/OT/2003vre.jpg -output /usr/OT/output
```

Is that right or not (the format of input and output)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: "but it wont work" ... what's wrong with it

Comment: So the format is right, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Hadoop streaming mapreduce framework works in stdin/stdout with key value pairs. So for a mapper to get input, it has to read from stdin and write to stdout a key value pair or pairs.

I think in octave there is no way of reading image from stdin and writing image to stdout. I.e. you cannot do:

```
 rgbImage = imread("STDIN")
```

or

```
 imwrite(rgbImage, "STDOUT")
```

Also you cannot give file path in HDFS for octave file operations. If you have your own imread and imwrite binaries which processes data via stdin and stdout then your workflow will be in the following way:

Mapper

```
#!/bin/bash

mapInpFileName=${map_input_file}  # Get input file name from env.

img=`cat`
rbgImage=`imread < $img`
oupImage=`imwrite < $rbgImage`
printf "%s\t%s\n" "$mapInpFileName" "$oupImage"
```

Make your reducer Identity.

Your output (in HDFS) will be only one file with naming part-0000. The format of this file will be:

```
filename1    Content of Image 1
filename2    Content of Image 2
...
```

Now you know, using this file you can generate images by some coding.

For input and output of hadoop streaming command, put all your image files in one dir of HDFS, say /usr/INP/. Then do:

```
hadoop@isro:/usr/local/grid/hadoop$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar -mapper /usr/OT/octave.sh -file /usr/OT/octave.sh -input /usr/INP/ -output /usr/OT/output
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Sandeep Kumar. I will work it out. But the matter is I am going to implement this in Matlab. Because my input file format is HDF, already i have stored all my hdf files in HDFS. So please tell me can i use this code in matlab. Is this works in matlab.

Comment: I have checked sir. But i got error (job failed). I did as you said. Can you please help me to do this. Just i need image read and write from HDFS. (mapper.sh) file?